# Equivalent to class functions

Tags: function, go, methods, struct

I came across a piece of code in Go,

```
type Person struct {
   Id int
}

func (Person) SayHello() (string) {
   return "Hello"
}
```

Is this equivalent to class functions in Go? what is the exact name of this? I could not find this in function receivers.

And also the calling part is like this-- `Person.SayHello(Person{})`
If Person{} have to be passed like this, then why use `func (Person) SayHello() (string)`
instead of `func (p *Person) SayHello() (string)`

Comment: There are no classes, or anything exactly equivalent to classes in Go, so there's no equivalent to "class functions".

Comment: It depends on your specific usage, but the simplest approach is just to make a normal function. If it's not a method, don't make it a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I could not find this in function receivers* ...

That's strange, because it is a function with a receiver.

- `func (Person) SayHello()` - a function with an unnamed receiver of type `Person`
- `func (p Person) SayHello()` - a function with a receiver `p` of type `Person`
- `func (p *Person) SayHello()` - a function with a receiver `p` of type pointer-to-`Person`

Value and pointer receivers have different uses, see e.g. [Choosing a value or pointer receiver](https://tour.golang.org/methods/8).

For example, `Person{}.SayHello()` won't work with a pointer receiver. But if the function needs to mutate the receiver, then there's no choice but to use a pointer receiver. Pointer receiver is most similar to the `this`-pointer in object-oriented languages (but note that naming the receiver `this`, `self` etc. is considered [bad style](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/3qoo36/question_why_is_self_or_this_not_considered_a/) in Go).

Answer (score 1):

All you have here is a method with an unnamed receiver parameter. It's valid in Go to omit parameter names, and this can make sense if you know you won't be using it.  This is covered in [this part](https://golang.org/ref/spec#ParameterDecl) of the spec.

The receiver is no different than any other function parameter in this regard. So some other similar examples would include:

```golang
func (p *Person) Do(string) {
    fmt.Println("I won't do what you ask.")
}
```

Related is the blank identifier, which can be used to ignore a subset of function parameters:

```golang
func (p *Person) DoAndSay(_, message string) {
    fmt.Println("I won't do what you want, but I will say it: %s", message)
}
```